# Regex select whole line without specific text (include \t) in front of the line

Tags: regex, notepad++

as per title, here are my data

eg.

```
<style1>   Name 1
<style2>Name 2
<style1>   Name 3
<style2>   Name4
```

assume there is `\t` after the `<style>` line 1,3 and 4

i'm using NotePad++ regex trying to get whole line on text which dont have `\t` after the "`<style>`"

Comment: `^<style\d+>[^\t].*`
answer from Borodin, perfect match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. This should do the trick

```
^<style\d+>[^\t].*
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Notepad++, but here' a regex for the whole line when there is no `\t` after the `<style>` (assuming that's what you mean):

```
/<style\d>[^\t].*/
```

Answer (score 0):

The following regex:

```
<style\d>\w+ \d+
```

Matched the following text:

`<style2>Name 2`

Answer (score 0):

```
^[^\t]+$
```

It has been test with notepad++. :). It works with your data, but this is the exact answer..

```
^<style\d>[^\t].*$
```

Comment: Will not work if there're some tabs after name (ie `name\t2\tfoobar`)